# Android view shaping like bottom app bar, but I need to use gradient

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-ui

Has anyone worked closely with the Material Shape Drawable and similar stuff?

The task is to make such a cutout without fail using a gradient and always with a fixed size. The implementation of the picture is not suitable.
And the cutout changes its size depending on whether the panel is closed or not

There are at least some ideas - I'm not sitting for the first day 
[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello friend this is called "cradle" of bottomAppBar FloatingActionButton.please refer here to learn more https://medium.com/@vadim.zhukov/easy-way-to-make-curved-bottomnavigationview-with-floatingactionbutton-12b979009e64

Comment: Thank you so much, friend:)